# scipy.optimize.fsolve: strange behavior when passing residual function in args

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I need to solve a large non-linear system many times using fsolve. I am used to C libraries where the residual function is passed as reference to avoid allocating memory every function call.

I have tried to pass a pre-allocated numpy array through the args to avoid allocating memory every time.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import time

def res_fun_A(x, n):
    F = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        F[i] = x[i] - 4.0
    return F


def res_fun_B(x, n, F):
    for i in range(n):
        F[i] = x[i] - 4.0
    return F

# params
niter = 1
ndim = 10
x0 = np.zeros(ndim)

## test A

time1 = time.time()

for t in range(niter):
    sol = fsolve(res_fun_A, x0, args = (ndim), full_output = True)

time2 = time.time()
print("Time elapsed method A: %g" % (time2 - time1))
print("Number of function evaluations: %d" % (sol[1]["nfev"]))
## test B


F = np.zeros(ndim)
for t in range(niter):
    sol = fsolve(res_fun_B, x0, args = (ndim, F), full_output = True)

time3 = time.time()
print("Time elapsed method B: %g" % (time3 - time2))
print("Number of function evaluations: %d" % (sol[1]["nfev"]))
```

Instead of improving the performance I have observed that fsolve takes many more iterations to converge. An example of this run with niter = 1 and ndim = 10 shows:

```
Time elapsed method A: 0.000240088
Number of function evaluations: 13
Time elapsed method B: 0.00118208
Number of function evaluations: 198
```

If I print the Jacobian:

```
Time elapsed method A: 0.00026226
Number of function evaluations: 13
         -1  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18117e-13  -2.18117e-13  -2.18117e-13  -2.18117e-13  -2.18103e-13
2.18103e-13            -1  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18076e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13            -1  -2.18117e-13  -2.18117e-13  -2.18089e-13  -2.18089e-13  -2.18089e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13            -1  -2.18076e-13  -2.18076e-13  -2.18076e-13  -2.18076e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18076e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13   2.18102e-13            -1  -2.18076e-13  -2.18076e-13  -2.18076e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18076e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13   2.18102e-13   2.18091e-13            -1  -2.18103e-13  -2.18103e-13  -2.18159e-13  -2.18103e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13   2.18102e-13   2.18091e-13   2.18159e-13            -1   -2.1802e-13  -2.18131e-13  -2.18076e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13   2.18102e-13   2.18091e-13   2.18159e-13   2.18128e-13            -1  -2.17881e-13  -2.17881e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13   2.18102e-13   2.18091e-13   2.18159e-13   2.18128e-13   2.17968e-13            -1  -2.18159e-13
2.18103e-13   2.18105e-13     2.181e-13   2.18102e-13   2.18091e-13   2.18159e-13   2.18128e-13   2.17968e-13    2.1827e-13            -1
Time elapsed method B: 0.00228786
Number of function evaluations: 198
-0.541673  -0.223227   -0.206905   -0.195436  0.711052   -0.0102151   -0.0160234   -0.0358565   0.245534    0.090698
        0   0.964094  -0.0678001  -0.0640418  0.233003  -0.00334735  -0.00525065   -0.0117497  0.0804584   0.0297206
        0          0    0.966859  -0.0636803  0.231687  -0.00332846  -0.00522102   -0.0116834  0.0800043   0.0295528
        0          0           0    0.968394  0.233733  -0.00335785  -0.00526712   -0.0117865  0.0807106   0.0298137
        0          0           0           0  0.349081    0.0361393    0.0566881     0.126854   -0.86866   -0.320875
        0          0           0           0         0     0.999256  -0.00233469  -0.00522448  0.0357757   0.0132152
        0          0           0           0         0            0     0.998166  -0.00821629  0.0562627   0.0207829
        0          0           0           0         0            0            0     0.990747   0.127312   0.0470277
        0          0           0           0         0            0            0            0   0.346506   -0.938048
-0.840589   0.143847    0.133329    0.125938   -0.4582   0.00658257    0.0103254    0.0231058  -0.158222  -0.0584455
```

With the second method the Jacobian is not correct. I am sure I am missing something that is happening under the hood with fsolve but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Hello. 4 years later, have you found a solution to this?